# SetInterval not working fine in Chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, dom-events

It's works fine for only 5 min in Chrome then the page doesn't respond; am I missing anything? This is my code. It works fine in Firefox and IE8 browsers:

```
function do(){
            // coding     
            setTimeout(do,30000);
            if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1){
                setInterval(do,20000);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

`do` is a reserved word I believe, in Chrome ( do.. while ):

```
function do(){}
SyntaxError: Unexpected token do
```

Try naming it differently?

**Wait: Why are you browser sniffing?**

Comment: ++ a better question is why the double compounded recursion. exponential recursion even?

Comment: Thanks for Your reply . I found that setInterval method will take 100% cpu usage in chrome browser only . see the link below
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25892

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Your reply . I found that setInterval method will take 100% cpu usage in chrome browser only . see the link below code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25892